# I have created a website using SQL. I want to know whether my website is safe from the SQL injections or not?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

The basic code which I used for the admin login and admin password is:

```
</style>
<div id="login-form">
  <div>


  </div>
  <div >
  <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2><hr>
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" 
class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" 
class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
```

I am not a security expert but I know some minor attacks like " admin' or 1=1#", "Admin' order by 1=1#" OR "test' or 5=5--" etc.
But none of them could breach the website.

I am always getting the following errors:-

1). You must provide username/mobile number and password
2). Password must be at least 6 characters long
3). This username doesn't exist in our database
4). The password does not match our record

Altogether.

I want to know whether my website is vulnerable to other attacks or not. If yes, then how can I protect it from those attacks.

It is important for me because I am designing this website myself for my new startup business and I don't have much funds yet so I cannot afford any security expert or web developer. So, I myself learned how to design a basic website and made it.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance!
Have a great day ahead.

Comment: It's going to depend on your `login.php` if your website is vulnerable or not. But why don't you use a standard PHP framework for building websites instead of rolling out your own?

Comment: And what code do you use for "binding" or "escaping" strings that are provided by the 'user' to be 'inserted' into the database?

Comment: I'd suggest backing up another step. Consider using WordPress for your website. This will minimize how much coding you need to do, and reduce your surface area for attack